# PagedList.Core.MVC tag helper not transferring model parameter to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, model-binding

I have a table with pagination in ASP.Net Core. I have a input where user can search the result by name and a Search button which works as expected. However after the search name input is searched and result is displayed, clicking on the new page number, the model parameter(search name) is not being transferred to the controller action method. The page parameter is however being transferred correctly. How do I go about fixing it?

```
@model FruitViewModel
@using PagedList.Core.Mvc

<form id="formPostFruit" asp-action="PostFruit" asp-controller="Fruit" asp-route-model="@Model" method="get">

<input name="SearchName" type="text" title="Search Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Search name" asp-for="SearchName" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" title="Search"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp;Search</button>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @if (Model.ResultList != null && Model.ResultList.Count() > 0)
        {

            @foreach (var item in Model.ResultList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Quantity
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Price
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
            }
        }
       
    </tbody>
</table>

@if (Model != null && Model.ResultList != null && Model.ResultList.Count() > 0 && Model.ResultList.PageCount > 1)
{
    <pager class="pager" list="@Model.ResultList" asp-action="PostFruit" asp- 
    controller="Fruit" asp-route-model="@Model" param-page-number="page" 
    options="@PagedListRenderOptions.Bootstrap4PageNumbersPlusFirstAndLast" />
}
```

The Controller action

```
public ActionResult PostFruit(FruitViewModel model, int? page)
{

}
```

Comment: You can store the parameter in a `Session` variable and retrieve it in your `PostFruit` method.

Comment: `list="@Model.ResultList"` means `@Model.ResultList` should be `IPagedList` type,why you can foreach `Model.ResultList`?